# Setter called on struct during access of computed variable with protocol cast

Tags: swift, struct, protocols, swift2, setter

I have created a global variable for a struct that adheres to a protocol. The variable has a setter observer that completes a task whenever the variable is set. Since the struct itself adheres to a protocol, I would like the type of the variable to be the protocol type.

```
protocol TestProtocol {
    var someInt: Int {get set}
    var computedVar: Int {get}
    func funcCall() -> Int
}

struct TestStruct: TestProtocol {
    var someInt: Int = 1

    var computedVar: Int {
        return 0
    } 

    func funcCall() -> Int {
        return 2
    }
}

var testProtocolVar: TestProtocol = TestStruct() {
    willSet(newTest) {
        print ("*** Setter testProtocolVar called!!!")
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I get the value of a protocol property that is a computed property in the struct, the variable setter is also called.

```
/***
  When a variable is defined and typecast as a protocol, calling a
  computed variable on the variable (a class or a struct) the setter 
  method of the variable will be called (Undesired Behaviour).
***/

print ("\n\n *** Test Protocol Cast Variable *** \n\n")
testProtocolVar
testProtocolVar.someInt
print("Setter has not been called")
testProtocolVar.funcCall()
print("Setter has not been called after function")
testProtocolVar.computedVar
print("Setter has been called when using computed variable")

/*
    *** Test Protocol Cast Variable *** 


   Setter has not been called
   Setter has not been called after function
   *** Setter testProtocolVar called!!!
   Setter has been called when using computed variable
*/
```

Similar scenario with variable being of a struct type does not get the setter triggered.

```
print ("\n\n *** Test Normal Cast Variable *** \n\n")

/***
  When a variable is defined and typecast as the struct type, calling a
  computed variable on the variable the setter method of the variable 
  will NOT be called (Desired Behaviour).
***/

var testVar:TestStruct = testProtocolVar as! TestStruct

testVar
testVar.someInt
print("Setter has not been called")
testVar.funcCall()
print("Setter has not been called after function")
testVar.computedVar
print("Setter has not been called when using computed variable")

/*
   *** Test Normal Cast Variable *** 


  Setter has not been called
  Setter has not been called after function
  Setter has not been called when using computed variable
*/
```

Does anyone have an explanation for why the setter observer is being called?

This seems like it is a bug in swift unless I am missing something.

Comment: Agreed. Looks like a bug to me.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be officially fixed in Xcode 7.2 beta 2

> Resolved Issues in Xcode 7.2 beta 2 - Swift 2.1 and Objective-C Swift
>   Compiler In previous releases of Swift, if a type had a mutable
>   property of protocol type, "chained" accesses to properties of that
>   property were always treated as mutations of the property, even if the
>   second property was only read, not written. For example:
>
> ```
>   protocol Countable {
>        var count: Int { get }
>   }
>   class MyObject {
>       var widgets : Countable {
>              didSet { print("in didSet") }
> } }
>   var obj : MyObject = ...
>   let count = obj.widgets.count
> ```
>
> This would perform a spurious write back to the property widgets,
>   causing didSet to unexpectedly fire. The workaround was to split the
>   access into separate expressions, like so:
>
> ```
>   let widgets = obj.widgets
>   let count = widgets.count
> ```
>
> This bug has now been fixed. (22953072)

Answer (score 0):

```
    protocol TestProtocol {
        var someInt: Int {get set}
        var computedVar: Int {get}
        func funcCall() -> Int
    }

    struct TestStruct: TestProtocol {
        var someInt: Int = 1
        var computedVar: Int {
            return 0
        }
        func funcCall() -> Int {
            return 2
        }
    }

    var testProtocolVar: TestProtocol = TestStruct() {
        willSet {
            print ("*** Setter testProtocolVar called!!!", newValue)
        }
    }

    var i: CustomStringConvertible = Int(10) {
        willSet {
            print("*** Setter Int called!!!", newValue)
        }
    }

    let a = testProtocolVar
    let b = a.computedVar
    let c = testProtocolVar.computedVar // *** Setter testProtocolVar called!!! TestStruct(someInt: 1)    
    let j = i
    let k = j.description
    let l = i.description // *** Setter Int called!!! 10
```

do you think it is a bug?? it seems fine for me ...

> The willSet and didSet observers provide a way to observe (and to
>   respond appropriately) when the value of a variable or property is
>   being set. The observers are not called when the variable or property
>   is first initialized. Instead, they are called only when the value is
>   set outside of an initialization context.

Comment: I am not sure why you think this should be the default behaviour. Calling the computedVar computer property should simply return 0. It should not result in the settings of the testProtocolVar. As an example, getting the someInt variable does not have this result.

Comment: i can imagine, that computed property value is computed with the set closure and reported with the get closure of 'general' stored property. even though the set closure is not available externally, it still should set the value before you receive it . this is in conformance with the citation above. as i understand it, this is the difference between computed properties and functions. willSet, set, didSet and get are generally not accessible externally and are part of property implementation. i understand, that our expectation are different but nobody tell us, so it is not a bug

Comment: by the way, the same code in Xcode Version 7.2 beta (7C46l) prints NOTHING :-)

Comment: Excellent. I had a filed a radar for this. Hopefully Apple agrees that it is a bug, and has fixed it ... that would be hopeful.